# Updating an MS Access database remotely

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

We have a few websites which are all on a dedicated server. The sites use an MS Access database back end (database per website). We have a few pages which were created to update/edit entries in the database, but I need to do more than that now. I can either create new aspx pages to update and manage the database, but I'd like to know if there are any simpler solutions?

Ideally, I'd love to create an application which can sit on our admin desktops which we could log in to and add/edit data. Similar to "forms" in MS Access.

I've looked at using "Pages" (MS Access 2003) but don't seem to have had much luck with this. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: You might like to look at Access 2010, but it requires Sharepoint for this kind of work, AFAIK: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use Remote Desktop and edit the access mdb/accdb files directly?

Comment: yes that's what I do as the admin, but our other staff need to update data and I don't want to give them access to the server. Looks like I might have to write the forms.

Comment: a local access db with forms running off linked tables would probably be your best solution then... though if the other users are confident with the data then maybe you can get away without the forms and just let them access the linked tables directly. They'd be able to add/edit/delete records but not change the design of the tables. Its not even close to a secure solution but would be sooo much less work for you

Comment: I ended up doing just this - thanks. Having the forms run from linked tables and setting up remote access for particular users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For remote access, have a look at team viewer. It's free and very good.